# How to enter q button after the command in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to enter "q" button right after the command I run. I found some commands but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```
echo -e "\q" | aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket $bucket_name
```

Any other ideas on this?

Comment: Why are you escaping the`q`?

Comment: I fixed it after your comment, but it didn't work. @Barmar

Comment: I rolled back your change, since my answer doesn't make sense with it.

Comment: Have you tried `aws --no-cli-pager` or setting `cli_pager` setting to blank as suggested on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html ?

Comment: You might look into `expect` for scripting interactive programs.

Comment: thanks, @omajid that resolved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

`q` is an ordinary character, it doesn't need to be escaped:

```
echo q | command
```

Comment: it didn't work. I'm trying to delete a bunch of s3 buckets with the command `echo q | aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket $bucket_name` and I see END screen each time in terminal. I can basically go back to the main screen once I entered `q`. Any other ideas on this?

Comment: This only works with programs that read from stdin, not full-screen applications.